# Неверное отображение дерева

Tags: java, swing

Есть дерево, JTree, узлы которого представлены в качестве чекбокса с меткой. Создал свой renderer и применил к своему дереву. Всё работает, но есть проблема: компонента, создаваемая рендерером, больше той, что получается у стандартного рендерера. И часть представления узла не видна, обрезана по высоте. В примере в интернете тоже такое есть:

[image]
<sub>(источник: [java2s.com](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaImages/CheckNodeTreeExample.PNG))</sub>

Как обойти такую проблему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сталкивался с такой проблемой. В [JTree](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html) высоту нода можно задать с помощью метода

```
setRowHeight(int rowHeight)
```

куда передать, например preferred height от вашего checkbox. 
Либо переопределить метод isFixedRowHeight:

```
public boolean isFixedRowHeight() {
    return false;
}
```

Тогда высота каждого отдельного нода будет только такой, какова высота компонента, созданного рендерером. При этом getRowHeight будет возвращать минус один. Второй случай xорош тем, что обрабатывает случай, когда у вас не все ноды с checkbox, а есть и другие. Т.е. должны быть разные высоты у разныx элементов.

Answer (score 2):

У меня с темой Metal и Nimbus не воспроизводится. К сожалению, у меня нет винды, так что нет возможности проверить. Полагаю, проблема в переключении Look And Feel. Дерево по какой-то причине неправильно оценивает размеры. Можно попробовать указать тему при старте приложения.

Кроме того, в примере на java2s явно рассчитываются размеры.. ну так попробуйте прибавить руками пару пикселов на всякий случай. Это, конечно, не правильно.. но.. что же делать.

В случае, если вы ставите LAF уже после создания окна, то тогда [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/2603).